Relative concentrations of ions in pure water with a pH of 7
Not a chemist here as the last Chemistry class I took was millennia ago, so please be patient with me. The Chem taught today is so different (and much harder) than I remember.
So, regarding pure water, I am curious about the relative ratios of water molecules to its constituent ions.
For example, for $1$ molar concentration of pure water, what is the relative ratio of the ions in the following reactions:

H2O <==> H+ and OH- ... I assume if its pH=7, then that H+/OH- concentration would be $10^{-7}$ molar?

H2O <==> H3O+ and OH- ... Would the ionic concentration be $10^{-7}$ molar?

Un-ionized H2O molecules would remain $1$ molar, hence the relative ratios are $10^7$ molecules of H2O per one each of the H+, OH-, H3O+ and OH- ions? ... i.e., $10^7:1:1:1:1$ for pure water ?


Do both cases appear in water randomly or is only case 1 or case 2 is valid?
Could it be that molecular H2O and OH- occur in equal amounts?
Thanks!
David

Pure water is about $\pu{55.5 M}$ solution. To make $\pu{1 M}$ solution of water you may need different solvent (e.g., may be ethanol). That solution most certainly not be in $\mathrm{pH} \ 7$.

Ok, the bigger issue is what the relative ratios of the ions to molecular water as described in the question.

What exactly do you mean by "1 molar concentration of pure water" ?

$\pu{1 L}$ of pure water at $\pu{25 ^{\circ}C}$ contains about $\pu{55.5 mol}$ of water and $\pu{100 nmol}$ (or $\pu{e-7 mol}$) of both $\ce{H+(aq)}$ and $\ce{OH^-(aq)}$ ions. Therefore, the ratios for both ions to water molecules are approximately $1 : 555,000,000$.
Real pure water almost always contains a small amount of dissolved atmospheric $\ce{CO2}$. When left to be in equilibrium with air, it leads to a $\ce{pH}$ decrease to about $\text{pH} \approx 5.6$. The molar ratios would then be approximately $55.5 : 10^{-5.6}$ for $\ce{H2O}$ : $\ce{H+(aq)}$ and $55.5 : 10^{5.6 - 14}$ for $\ce{H2O}$ : $\ce{OH^-(aq)}$.
Note that $\ce{H+}$, $\ce{H3O+}$, $\ce{H+(aq)}$, and $\ce{H3O+(aq)}$ are technically the same in the context of aqueous solutions, differing only in formal notation. The preferred notation is $\ce{H+(aq)}$.
Note that $\ce{H+}$ itself is free "naked" proton $\ce{p}$, a subatomic particle with an extremely intense electrostatic field. It immediately bonds to the nearest $\ce{H2O}$ molecule. However, the structure of hydrated protons is complex, and $\ce{H3O+(aq)}$ is not exactly correct.
A mixture of $\ce{H2O}$ and $\ce{OH^-}$ in a 1:1 ratio is not possible. If such a mixture were somehow created and then the magical force holding it in place was removed, it would result in a gigantic Coulombic explosion due to the massive electrostatic repulsion forces between the $\ce{OH^-}$ ions.

Thank you very much for this clear explanation for a non-chemist such as I. The real reason behind this question was that knowing that cytosol in a cell contains 70% water (and the rest other stuff) and with potassium concentration of 120-150mmoL/L inside the cell (much lower outside at 3-5mmol/L) ... what is the relative concentration of intracellular potassium to the cytosol or water inside the cell? Big complicated math thing for me but probably easy and trivial for you :-). Thanks!

Concentration c = n/V, the molar amount referring to volume, regardless what the volume represents.
